# What is the correct regex to accomplish string split in java?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a String `"50[=]Test Item"` that I want to split in java using `String.split` to get `"50"` and `"Test Item"`. What is the correct regex to accomplish that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You don't even need regex... aren't you splitting by the exact pattern [=] here?

Comment: [/[=/]], but that only matches = and give me "50[" and "]Test Item"

Comment: well, spliting with [=] results in the same as "50[" and "]Test Item"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape `[`, while splitting, as it is special character in regex. You just need to escape `[` because it starts a character class. No need to escape `]`:

```
Arrays.toString("50[=]Test Item".split("\\[=]"));
```

will give you:

```
[50, Test Item]
```

Comment: So, since you escape the `[`, the `]` is no longer interpreted as a special character?

Comment: @SteveP. Yes. `]` is used to close the opened character class. Escaping `[`, doesn't start a character class, so it just matches a `]`.

Comment: @SteveP. Similar is the case with `{` and `}`. If you escape `{`, you don't need to escape `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the [ and ] characters since `split` accepts a regular expression, and not a simple string. In a regular expression, the characters `[` and `]` have special meaning, indicating a character class. Thus, you might want to try the following:

```
String[] splits = yourVar.split("\\[=\\]");
```